# sqlsvr_fetch_array within fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

So I have a PHP script I am convering from MSSQL to SQLSRV and I am having some difficulty.

I have this

```
 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{

$time = time() - strtotime('today');

$row2sql = "SELECT SUM(mnyAmount) AS 'Total' FROM dbo.tblTransactions WHERE intPerson='".$row[intPerson]."'";
$row3sql = "SELECT SUM(mnyAmount) AS 'Total' FROM dbo.tblTransactions WHERE intPerson='".$row[intPerson]."' AND strDate>'".$row[strDate]."' AND mnyAmount<'0'";
$row4sql = "SELECT SUM(mnyAmount) AS 'Total' FROM dbo.tblTransactions WHERE intPerson='".$row[intPerson]."' AND strDate>'".$row[strDate]."' AND mnyAmount>'0'";

$row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($row2sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($row3sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($row4sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Which essentially pulls data based on the search and then cross references their data per row. In MySQL this wouldn't be a problem - but seem to be having difficult here?

Basically, if I search "Smith" it will bring up all users with Smith in their name...(for example three rows) then I want it to get each of their balances respectively.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the fixed code. The first parameter of sqlsrv_fetch_array has to be a resource, you're giving a string here. You have to execute the query first before "unzipping" it.

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{

$time = time() - strtotime('today');

$row2sql = "SELECT SUM(mnyAmount) AS 'Total' FROM dbo.tblTransactions WHERE intPerson='".$row[intPerson]."'";
$row3sql = "SELECT SUM(mnyAmount) AS 'Total' FROM dbo.tblTransactions WHERE intPerson='".$row[intPerson]."' AND strDate>'".$row[strDate]."' AND mnyAmount<'0'";
$row4sql = "SELECT SUM(mnyAmount) AS 'Total' FROM dbo.tblTransactions WHERE intPerson='".$row[intPerson]."' AND strDate>'".$row[strDate]."' AND mnyAmount>'0'";
//$connection is the connection variable you get from opening a connection to the database
$result2 = sqlsrv_query($connection, $row2sql);
$result3 = sqlsrv_query($connection, $row3sql);
$result4 = sqlsrv_query($connection, $row4sql);
$row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result4, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, this worked. You have really helped me there, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the call to sqlsrv_query for each  of  your queries.

i.e. you should have something like this for each of your sub queries (see example 1 http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(mnyAmount) AS 'Total' FROM dbo.tblTransactions WHERE intPerson='".$row[intPerson]."'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Given that you have used both MySQL and SQLServer, it is probably worth looking at using PDO (https://www.php.net/pdo). This will allow you to alter configuration instead of having to edit code should you need to change db server. It also makes code consistent.

Comment: If you feel this is the answer, I'd appreciate it if you could set it as so.